# WSDL in Python with and url + authentification + endpoint

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, endpoint

I'm new in WSDL, and I'd like to consume an WSDL in Python with and URL + endpoint.

The information:

URL:https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500

Username: Ws_cgr

Password: Claves+2021

and endpoint:
https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding

I tried both suds and zeep.

```
# suds

from suds.client import Client

url = "https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500"

mhws = Client(url, username='Ws_cgr', password='Claves+2021')


print(mhws)
```

and zeep

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth 
from requests import Session
from zeep import Client
from zeep.transports import Transport

url = "https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500"

username = 'Ws_cgr' 
password = 'Claves+2021'


r = requests.get(url, auth=(username, password))

print(r.status_code)

session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
client = Client(url,
            transport=Transport(session=session))
```

The three methods that contain the information in the WSDL are ZwsYMhd76000042, ZwsZfmMensual and ZwsZinforme37Newm, and I need to consume the information from those methods.

In both cases I can access the WSDL, but not so I can consume it. I don't really know how to put the endpoint information in python code to consumen the WSDL.

I used options like proxies, and others, but without anything clear and concrete.

Could you help me on this subject please?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try to use this url :https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from zeep import Client
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from zeep.transports import Transport


wsdl = "https://sigaf.hacienda.go.cr/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A111AD1/bndg_url/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zfmg_reports/500/zfmg_reports/binding?sap-client=500?wsdl"
username = 'Ws_cgr' 
password = 'Claves+2021'


session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth(username, password)
client = Client(wsdl, transport=Transport(session=session))
 

r = client.service.methodYouWant()
```